# problem with query+php+json

Tags: php, mysql, json, character-encoding

i have this code to search in the bd for values identically to design

```
<?php
include("includes/banco.php");
$theclass->conecta();

$more= "design";  

$rs = mysql_query('select abcd from house where abcd like "'.$more .'%"');

$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['abcd']  
        );
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
flush();

?>
```

In the bd i have design in the first id and design gráfico in the second id

the result is this:

```
[{"label":"Design"},{"label":null}]
```

if i change the bd to design grafico the result is

```
[{"label":"Design"},{"label":"Design grafico"}]
```

so, it has some problem with the codification or what?

thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is completely unclear.

Comment: Eesh.. If $more is actually going to be populated with user input, $_GET or $_POST data (or anything else external), I hope you're planning on properly sanitizing it.

Comment: it is the next step, but now the problem is other, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did your database encoding is UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 ?
If it is UTF-8, try

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

after connect to mysql.

Comment: If your DBMS MySQL is configured by default to UTF-8 then "SET NAMES UTF-8" is not necessary.